# Custom Layout of Listitem not Updating after notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my application I have two activity, one which contain Recycleview and another one which is responsible for updating database value,in OnBind method of adpater I am updating thoes values(font size and color).I was able to getting change in fontsize and color according to update but Layout which contain thoes item not changing it's hight.

I am posting link of output thoes are in sequence , first one is without edit(https://ibb.co/931P0Q4), Second is with edit(https://ibb.co/KzY7VCL), Theird is after restart app(https://ibb.co/C7cqf7Z)

**Code of my custom item:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainLainerHOlder"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.chauthai.swipereveallayout.SwipeRevealLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_layout_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:mode="normal"
        app:dragEdge="right">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/cEditText"
                android:background="@color/initColor"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="Edit"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/cDeleteText"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:text="Delete"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/MianLinearLayoutContainer"
            android:background="@drawable/border_solid_white">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Name will here"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/nametxtl"
                        android:textSize="20dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Number here"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/nutxtl"
                        android:textSize="20dp"/>


                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.chauthai.swipereveallayout.SwipeRevealLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Code inside onResume by that I was able to get updated changes:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.e("onResume","yes");
    TDataRead();
    customRecycleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

here TdataRead is just method by which I m geting updating data for notify.

code of TdataRead:

```
public void TDataRead() {

        customDataListModelList.clear();
        Cursor cursor = tempSqliteDatabaseHelper.getAllData();
        if (cursor.getCount() == 0) {
            Log.e("No_temp", "No temp Contact Selected");
            return;
        }

        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {


            customDataListModelList.add(new CustomDataListModel((cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getInt(4), cursor.getInt(5)));
            stringBuffer.append("Id :" + cursor.getString(0) + "\n");
            stringBuffer.append("Name :" + cursor.getString(1) + "\n");
            stringBuffer.append("Number :" + cursor.getString(2) + "\n");
            stringBuffer.append("color :" + cursor.getString(3) + "\n");
            stringBuffer.append("Font Size :" + cursor.getInt(4) + "\n");
            stringBuffer.append("Index:" + cursor.getInt(5) + "\n");

            Log.e("CustomDataRecord", String.valueOf(customDataListModelList.get(i).Name));

        }

    }
```

I thing solution is reside with calling onBind method again or somerhing by list reload itself. and reload means calling contrustor of adapter again.I don't think thats proper way. if u have any other suggestion help me.

Comment: Post the code for TDataRead(); and while you're at it read this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/

Comment: @ivan wooll u can see code updated post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by calling xview.setAdapter(xAdapter) in onResume method means that for updated layout changes RecyclerView need updated instance of Adapter.

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        TDataRead();
        customRecycleAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recyleview.setAdapter(customRecycleAdapter);

    }
```